# Enable a button when user mark a checkbox inside a list item

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I'm developing an Android 3.1 application.

I have a `ListView` with items with this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/itemCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is activity's layout with **list**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="629dp" >
    </ListView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/downloadFormsButton"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="@string/download_forms_button" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/formErrorMsg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

How can enable `downloadFormsButton` when user selects one or more List items' checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement an onCheckedChangeListener for your checkbox and manage a list of checked items in your adapter . Whenever the checked state is changed check to see if your list of checked items is empty and enable/disable your button based on that.

```
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
            {
                if (isChecked)
                    checkedItems.add(itemId);
                else
                    checkedItems.remove(itemId);

                downloadFormsButton.setEnabled(checkedItems.size() > 0); //sets button enabled = true if size is greater than 0.

            }
        });
```